# Problems referencing Facebook SDK in Android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I have been trying to use FBConnect in my app but whenever I try to reference the SDK, it doesn't quite do it.
This is the screenshot

[image]

Please help. I am stuck for past 4 hours. Nothing found on google or here on SO

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219627/how-to-properly-configure-facebook-android-sdk-using-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this page: http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/android/845/. Seems like you should add the JAR file. What you did here is add a library - an open project in Eclipse that serves as a library for another project.

Comment: I have been following the instructions provided by facebook itself. Your method would only give me fbconnect option, but I need other stuff too. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/

Comment: Ok. Try to remove the library, and remove the jar files in your project's bin folder. Also make sure that no references are left in the Android Dependencies folder in Eclipse. Then add the facebook library again.

Answer (score 0):

Clarification:  when you click add, you see "FacebookSDK".  It shows as valid until you close the properties dialog.  Then when you open the dialog again, it has a red X next to it.

If that is what is happening to you...  I ran into the same thing a long time ago.  The facebook sdk needs to be in the same parent folder as your project.

For example, if you are running out of c:\users\me\workspace\my cool project,
the facebook sdk needs to be in c:\users\me\workspace\facebook-android-skd-2.0.2.b

No idea why, but after beating my head against the wall over this for a couple of days I figured it out.